# UAC "missing write permissions" error while installing XAMPP on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, xampp

I am facing the following issue while installing XAMPP through a PowerShell script on Windows:

> Important! Because an activated User Account Control (UAC) on your system some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted. With UAC please avoid to install XAMPP to C:\Program Files (x86) (missing write permisssions). Or deactivate UAC with msconfig after this setup. Error copying file from packed archive C:/xampp-win32-5.6.30-0-VC11-installer.exe to C:/xampp/service.exe Abort There has been an error. Unable to copy file

I have executed the PowerShell script from Jenkins.

I have alsoe disabled UAC, but still I am facing the same issue. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Most probably UAC has not been effectively disabled. Try to edit this registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Set

> EnableLUA

to

> 0x00000000

Also make sure you run everything as an Administrator.

Comment: Here is the registry MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232765.aspx?ranMID=24542&ranEAID=TnL5HPStwNw&ranSiteID=TnL5HPStwNw-BkBN5gHtBFOLta6sSjI0eQ&tduid=(04f2c529d31350350794ff0bdabac91f)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-BkBN5gHtBFOLta6sSjI0eQ)()

Comment: But now i facing this error while installing xampp,

Comment: Error copying file from packed archive C:/xampp-win32-5.6.30-0-VC11-installer.exe to C:/xampp/service.exe Abort There has been an error. Unable to copy file

Comment: Have you checked the registry? Are you starting powershell "As Administrator"? Open powershell as admin and then execute the script. Are you installing to 'C:\Program Files (x86)' or something else? Try to install to some custom directory like for e.g. 'C:/xampp' and make sure you add all permissions to that directory.